# Web hosting on AWS - Where do we create the database and how to link S3 to EC2

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, web-hosting, amazon-simpledb

I usually use webhosts with cpanel.
I'm trying a larger scale website so I thought I'll give AWS a try.
I've been googling and reading the documentations but still can't find a step by step guide to get my website live.

I've transferred all my files to S3
what do I do with EC2?
How do I create a mySQL database?

Thank you for your help.
David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For setting MySQL database, there are two options :

1. Setup MySQL in your EC2 instance. This is same like as we do in normal scenario.
2. Make use of Amazon RDS for database. Launch an Amazon RDS instance and give EC2 security group permissions to RDS security group. Access the newly created RDS instance by making use of endpoint name. Advantage of having RDS instance is you don't have to worry about backups and version upgrades.

Attach an EBS volume to your EC2 instance and store everything in that. EBS volumes can be attached on the fly. Your data persists even if EC2 instance crashes out. We can create snapshots of EBS volume and store them in S3 for backups.

Regards,
Sanket Dangi

Comment: you do not need RDS. You can just add a EBS volume that stores MySQL data and attach that to MySQL server running on any instance. Point MySQL to newly attached volume. Done.

Comment: @Nishant thanks! How do you point MySQL to the attached volume?